# How can I sort a list of dates in apex

Tags: apex

Dates=<21-01-2019, 01-02-2019, 10-10-2000>;

Dates.sort();

Gives -< 01-02-2019, 10-10-2000, 21-01-2019>

I want - <10-10-2000, 21-01-2019, 01-02-2019>

Comment: It sounds like you're using `String` values instead of `Date` values. This would give you the problem you're seeing. They need to be actual date values, or formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: @sfdcfox forgot to mention , it is In string format, is there any workaround?

Comment: I suppose you could write a util function that gets a list of String objects (formatted as dates), converts them to Date objects, sorts them, and returns a list of Strings. A simple CompSci 101 exercise, but not something I'd love to do in a production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort by year, month, then day, this means that you need to convert to a date or parse the date values yourself. Here's a sample implementation.

```
Pattern datePattern = Pattern.compile('(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)');
public class DateWrapper implements Comparable {
  public String sourceValue;
  public Date dateValue;
  public DateWrapper(String source) {
    sourceValue = source;
    Matcher m = datePattern.match(source);
    dateValue = Date.newInstance(m.group(3), m.group(2), m.group(1));
  }
  public Integer compareTo(Object other) {
    return ((DateWrapper)other).dateValue.daysBetween(dateValue);
  }
}
```

---

```
DateWrapper[] values = new DateWrapper[0];
for(String dateString: dates) {
  values.add(new DateWrapper(dateString));
}
values.sort();
dates.clear();
for(DateWrapper wrapper: values) {
  dates.add(wrapper.sourceValue);
}
```